# What parts of Ubuntu are not written to often?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I'm thinking of purchasing a solid state drive for my computer, to install my operating systems on. It's my understanding that SSDs don't like being written to often, so I want to make sure that the drive isn't written to more than necessary.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Well, I understand that solid state drives cannot handle as many writes as hard drives, so I was wondering which parts of Ubuntu are not often written to.

For example, if I put /root on a solid state drive, and /home on another drive, will /root still be written to often?

Comment: You mean, you like to install parts of the Ubuntu which doesn't get written often on a SSD? I am not sure, if thats even possible.

Comment: But if I put /home on the HDD, and the rest of the system files on an SSD, will the SDD see much lower writes, because it does not contain /home?

Comment: It could be the vice-versa. SDD might get lesser writes if the /home is mounted on it, provided the user doesnt do any writes.

Comment: Where are all my applications (such as Steam) going to write to? I want that on the hard drive, and the critical OS files on the SSD.

Comment: I am not sure about Steam. But most of the applications write logs.

Answer (score 0):

It's a non-issue. To wear out a 10,000 cycles 64 GB SSD, you'd have to write 10,000 times 64 GBs, that is, 64 GBs a day per 27 years. Way too much for an average user.

It was a problem when SSDs had less cycles and thus wore out early.

Comment: It's a non-issue indeed, but the reason is slightly different. A long long time back the SSD controllers weren't rotating the blocks on the physical flash memory and filesystem metadata updated often (e.g. the journal) which caused the flash cells to be hit every few seconds. Nowadays these controllers are much more intelligent.

Comment: @gertvdijk: you should write it in an answer. I'd appreciate a link to a discussion where that's elaborated.

Comment: ... or an article or explanation of another kind, not necessarily a discussion